# websphere liberty - SLF4J jars conflicting with websphere internal bundles

Tags: java, jpa, osgi, websphere-liberty

I have an OSGi Application, that contains 3 bundles -

1 - LoggingWrapper, which acts as a wrapper for log4j and slf4j jars, and exports org.slf4j.* packages.

2 - MyProject, this contains JPA code, and imports the following packages:

```
Import-Package: javax.management,
 javax.naming,
 javax.persistence;version="1.1.0",
 javax.persistence.criteria;version="1.1.0",
 javax.persistence.metamodel;version="1.1.0",
 javax.sql;version="0.0.0",
 javax.transaction;version="1.1.0",
 javax.transaction.xa;version="1.1.0",
 org.apache.openjpa.enhance;version="2.2.0",
 org.apache.openjpa.util;version="2.2.0",
 org.slf4j
```

Deploying this on the server results in the following error:

```
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0404E: An exception was generated when trying to resolve the contents of the application JpaTestApp.  The exception text from the OSGi framework is: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource MyProject [IFileAdapter wrapping file with url file:/D:/programs/WebSphere/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps/JpaTestApp.eba/MyProject_1.0.0.jar] because it is exposed to package 'org.slf4j' from resources LoggingWrapper [IFileAdapter wrapping file with url file:/D:/programs/WebSphere/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps/JpaTestApp.eba/LoggingWrapper_1.0.0.jar] and com.ibm.ws.slf4j-api.1.7.7 [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="com.ibm.ws.slf4j-api.1.7.7"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.0.7.cl50420141211-1039"] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  MyProject [IFileAdapter wrapping file with url file:/D:/programs/WebSphere/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps/JpaTestApp.eba/MyProject_1.0.0.jar]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=0.0.0))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: org.slf4j
  LoggingWrapper [IFileAdapter wrapping file with url file:/D:/programs/WebSphere/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps/JpaTestApp.eba/LoggingWrapper_1.0.0.jar]

Chain 2:
  MyProject [IFileAdapter wrapping file with url file:/D:/programs/WebSphere/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps/JpaTestApp.eba/MyProject_1.0.0.jar]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.openjpa.util)(version>=2.2.0))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.openjpa.util; uses:=org.slf4j
  com.ibm.ws.jpa [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="com.ibm.ws.jpa"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.0.7.cl50420141211-1039"]
    import: (osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: org.slf4j
  com.ibm.ws.slf4j-api.1.7.7 [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="com.ibm.ws.slf4j-api.1.7.7"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.0.7.cl50420141211-1039"]
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0020I: Application JpaTestApp not updated.
```

Removing the "LoggingWrapper" bundle from the application, causes the following error:

```
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0404E: An exception was generated when trying to resolve the contents of the application JpaTestApp.  The exception text from the OSGi framework is: Unable to resolve IFileAdapter wrapping file with url file:/D:/programs/WebSphere/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/experimentalServer/apps/JpaTestApp.eba/XLetDBUtility_1.0.0.jar: missing requirement org.apache.aries.subsystem.core.archive.ImportPackageRequirement: namespace=osgi.wiring.package, attributes={}, directives={filter=(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=0.0.0))}, resource=IFileAdapter wrapping file with url file:/D:/programs/WebSphere/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/experimentalServer/apps/JpaTestApp.eba/XLetDBUtility_1.0.0.jar
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0012I: The application JpaTestApp was not started.
```

How can these errors be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Although Liberty is designed to insulate applications from open source libraries included in the runtime (such as slf4j), it seems there is a bit of leakage if some of the openjpa packages are imported. You should be able to use JPA in your application without importing the org.apache.openjpa* packages, so your best bet is to avoid them. Switching to dynamic runtime enhancement (rather than build-time enhancement) will save a build step and also allow you to remove the openjpa package imports.

Comment: Not including the org.apache.openjpa.* dependencies gives me the error `org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PersistenceCapable was not found by MyProject_1.0.0`. I am also not using build time enhancement at present, although I have tried doing so to resolve this. How do I enable dynamic enhancement (assuming it isn't the default)?

Comment: I checked whether I am using build-time enhancement using a decompiler - enhanced classes inherit from `PersistenceCapable`. The deployed class files are not enhanced. Also, removing `org.slf4j` but leaving openjpa dependencies allows me to use the bundle, but prevents me from using loggers in it.